# Send data from HTML form to php

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to send data from HTML to PHP. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <form action="email-script.php" method="post">
      <div class="contact-form mar-top30">
        <label> <span>Full name</span>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="name" id="name"/>
        </label>
        <label> <span>Email</span>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="email" id="email"/>
        </label>
        <label> <span>Subject</span>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="subject" id="subject"/>
        </label>
        <label> <span>Message</span>
        <textarea class="message" name="feedback" id="feedback"></textarea>
        </label>
        <label>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And here is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["name"] . "Sent this email" . "\r\n" . $_POST["feedback"] . "Sent from this email address:" . $_POST["email"];
    mail("email@gmail.com", $subject, $message);
    //header("Location: index.html");
?>
Error, please contact Jack at (email@gmail.com) <br>
email: <?php $email ?> <br>
subject: <?php $subject ?> <br>
message: <?php $message ?> <br>
</html>
```

I was thinking the best way to do this was through a POST method. How do I go about sending all of the data from the html form to the php email script via the click of the submit button. Posted below are screenshots of the issue.

Before submit:
[image]

After submit:
 [image]

Comment: By clicking the submit button?

Comment: yea, I want the submit button to send the email. The problem is in my debugging, all of the fields (email, message, etc...) are blank.

Comment: ha ha ha.lol. but i have to agree with @Don'tPanic

Comment: your php code is written in .php or .html ?

Comment: The top page is contact.php, and the second it email-script.php

Comment: if you click on submit , the form redirect you to address of the action attribute and pass form inputs via post , I don't understand what's your problem :|

Comment: @aidin the problem is that the php variables do not contain what I want them to. See the screenshots for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add echo before your output variables

```
email: <?php echo $email ?> <br>
subject: <?php echo $subject ?> <br>
message: <?php echo $message ?> <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

the vars are not empty you just forgot  `echo` them change your code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["name"] . "Sent this email" . "\r\n" . $_POST["feedback"] . "Sent from this email address:" . $_POST["email"];
    mail("email@gmail.com", $subject, $message);
    //header("Location: index.html");
?>
Error, please contact Jack at (email@gmail.com) <br>
email: <?php echo $email ?> <br>
subject: <?php echo  $subject ?> <br>
message: <?php echo  $message ?> <br>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check if `email-script.php` was accessed with a post request to avoid an errors occurring if the file is accessed directly.

Just surround the php script with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
     // validate the fields, send the email, etc.
}
```

and you're fine for the next request.

You should also validate the fields before sending the email, so noone can send you empty emails. If you want to add more security set a session or use google captcha so it's harder to submit the form multiple times consecutively.

Comment: I plan on trimming whitespace and sanitizing my data. This is just a first step in getting set up. I'll try this.